# make: Nothing to be done for 'build'

Tags: linux, make

I am learning C++, though I have now a general question, i.e. not for programmers, but IMHO best fit for Linux users.

I want the:

```
make
```

command to always build a new binary, which could easily be accomplished by creating a Bash alias, something like:

```
alias make='\make clean && \make'
```

**I would like not to be defining that `alias`, can this be achieved on the `Makefile`'s side?**

The simplest `Makefile`, I could come up with, follows:

```
PROGRAM=project

CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors

OPTIMIZATION=-O2

.PHONY: build
.PHONY: clean
.PHONY: distrib

build: ${PROGRAM}

clean:
    rm ${PROGRAM}

distrib:
    tar -czf ${PROGRAM}.tar.gz ${PROGRAM}.cpp Makefile

${PROGRAM}:
    g++ ${PROGRAM}.cpp ${CXXFLAGS} ${OPTIMIZATION} -o ${PROGRAM}
```

Now, in this state it says:

> ```
> make: Nothing to be done for 'build'.
> ```

Essentially, it probably sees recent timestamp and does not build, I think.

**EDIT1:**

I will only add, that this *issue* is not <kbd>Tab</kbd> related, it builds normal when binary is not in place.

**EDIT2:**

After I have made modifications as per Sato Katsura's answer:

The `Makefile` looks like this:

https://www.vlastimilburian.cz/public/linux/Makefile.gz

(I uploaded it, because Tabs can't be shown in text)

and it still says as the above information:

> ```
> make: Nothing to be done for 'build'.
> ```

**EDIT3:**

```
$ make --version

GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: You told `make` that `build` depends on `${PROGRAM}`, but didn't tell it that `${PROGRAM}` depends on `${PROGRAM}.cpp`

Comment: Change `${PROGRAM}:` to `${PROGRAM}: ${PROGRAM}.cpp`.  Add header files on the same line if any.

Comment: Ah yes, you also need to use `$(...)` to expand variables, not `${...}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick checklist:

- use TABs to indent action lines (`rm`, `tar`, `g++` etc.)
- use `$(FOO)` to expand variable `FOO` instead of `${FOO}` or `$FOO`
- add dependencies where relevant.

Your `Makefile` should look something like this (again, lines are indented with TABs, not spaces):

```
PROGRAM=project
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors
OPTIMIZATION=-O2

.PHONY: build
.PHONY: clean
.PHONY: distrib      

build: $(PROGRAM)

clean:
        rm $(PROGRAM)

distrib:
        tar -czf $(PROGRAM).tar.gz $(PROGRAM).cpp Makefile

$(PROGRAM): $(PROGRAM).cpp
        g++ $(PROGRAM).cpp $(CXXFLAGS) $(OPTIMIZATION) -o $(PROGRAM)
```

Comment: At least for GNU make, braces for variable substitution are allowed I think: see [Basics of Variable References](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html)

Comment: @steeldriver Could be, but using them is a bad idea, since `{...}` are shell patterns in some contexts.

Answer (score 3):

I have found [the answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8562379/1997354).

I quote:

> Make is behaving correctly. `hello` already exists and is not older than the `.c` files, and therefore there is no more work to be done. There are four scenarios in which make will need to (re)build:
>
> - If you modify one of your `.c` files, then it will be newer than `hello`, and then it will have to rebuild when you run make.
> - If you delete `hello`, then it will obviously have to rebuild it
> - You can force make to rebuild everything with the `-B` option. `make -B all`
> - `make clean all` will delete `hello` and require a rebuild. (I suggest you look at @Mat's comment about `rm -f *.o hello`

---

I will therefore stop insisting on building always, unless I change the source code file, which was what I incorrectly evaluated as a sort of an error before. If I indeed change the source code, the first time I run `make`, it builds correctly. And there is obviously no point to build it for a second time, so it is intelligent, man may say.

For those wanting to re-build always under any circumstances, you may define something like:

```
alias make='make -B'
```

or more self-explanatory:

```
alias make='make --always-make'
```

But beware, it states that it will:

> ```
> Unconditionally make all targets.
> ```

The `all targets` smells bad to me, so I won't use it. Anyway, I state it here, so we know for future reference.